# GPU computing: how much VRAM do I need for mini batch gradient descent?

Tags: parallel, gpu

I want to do some GPU computing with an NVIDIA card, and am deciding between having a GTX 960 with a 2GB or 4GB ram. Which one should I take? How much difference would these make in terms of the batch size I can use for mini batch gradient descent? Would this difference be significant?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Just get one with 4GB - there's a price difference of 10EUR.

Answer (score 1):

Generally memory cost increases linearly while mini-batch size increases. If batch size 32 costs you 2GB memory, then batch size 64 will cost you 4GB memory.

In practice, deep learning framework(for instance, [keras](https://keras.io/)) will load the **entire** full-batch into your memory, thus you cannot observe apparent memory increment or decrement during mini-batch tuning.

### References

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/146